# Is it possible to get a MySQL blob original file size if the size of the original file was not saved?

Tags: mysql, c#-4.0

Sadly I need to work on a system where previous devs decided that saving pdf files as blobs in the database is a good idea. I need to create pdf's from the blobs and they did not save the original file size in the db with the record.

I am using C# to this. I can set a hard coded size and yes it creates the files but all pdf's have the size specified regardless of the content. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have tried using MySQL query

SELECT OCTET_LENGTH(file_content)  as total_size FROM table where id = '1' 
but size is too small.

```
              UInt32 FileSize = MySqlCon.BlobSize(message.id);
            byte[] rawData;
            FileStream fs;
            string fileName = @"E:\Attachments\" + message.FileName;

            string u = "select file_content from message where id ='" + message.id + "'";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(u, MyCon);
            MySqlDataReader myData;
            try
            {
                MyCon.Open();
                myData = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (!myData.HasRows)
                    throw new Exception("There are no BLOBs to save");

                myData.Read();
                rawData = new byte[FileSize];

                myData.GetBytes(myData.GetOrdinal("file_content"), 0, rawData, 0, (int)FileSize);

                fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
                fs.Write(rawData, 0, (int)FileSize);
                fs.Close();

                Console.WriteLine("File successfully written to disk!");

                myData.Close();
                MyCon.Close();
                message.FilePath = fileName;
            }
```

Comment: I think I might have a temp solution until someone can give me a better solution.
When using 
SELECT OCTET_LENGTH(file_content) as total_size FROM table where id = '1' 
I get a result and then times that by 1.2. This is a real hack so if anyone could give me a better solution it would be great.

UInt32 FileSize = Convert.ToUInt32(MySqlCon.BlobSize(message.id) * 1.2);

Comment: `OCTET_LENGTH(file_content)` should indeed return the actual filesize, so you may have an error in your code. Please share your actual code where you try to use that value, your current code writes 80k-files, no matter if the blob is larger or smaller - e.g. it is not using the filesize, while your question states you have a problem with the value of the filesize. (Actually, you would not even need to query the size as `GetBytes` knows the size of the file/blob, but again, if we see your actual code, we might spot your problem.)